# Access 1 Comport from Multiple Forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, serial-port

I have a Visual Studio project (for RS232 communication) with multiple forms and I want to access the same `SerialPort` on all of my forms.

My main form calls out ...

`private SerialPort comport = new SerialPort()`

If I change it to `public` will I be able to access this `SerialPort` from all of my windows in order to ensure I read/write to the same port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will work as long as the other forms have some way of getting the main form's instance. One way would be to pass `this` to the forms when you create them from the main form. Then change the other form constructors to accept a Form object. The forms can use that object to access the `comport` property:

```
// Main form
private void OpenSomeForm()
{
    SomeForm frm = new SomeForm(this);
    frm.Show();
}

// SomeForm
public class SomeForm
{
    private MainForm _mainForm;

    public SomeForm(MainForm mainForm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _mainForm = mainForm;
    }

    private WriteToSerialPort()
    {
        _mainForm.comport.Write(/* stuff */);
    }
}
```

Comment: Underneath `InitializeComponent();` you wrote `_mainForm = mainForm`. What does the `mainForm` on the right side of the equation represent? I am getting an error "mainForm is a type but is used like a variable".

Comment: It's the name of the parameter passed into the constructor. `_mainForm` is the class field. `mainForm` is passed in. It's probably just confusing that the names are so similar, but they don't need to be.

Comment: @Nevets BTW, this is also a great place to use a singleton.